# My .jar file is not working in java

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have created an application and it is working correctly when I am executing it through NETBEANS.

After that I had clicked on "Clean and Build" to build a SiteScrapper.jar file. Now when I am executing it through command prompt by invoking the following dos command:

```
java -jar "SiteScrapper.jar"
```

I am getting the following exception

```
sitescrapper.Main class not found
```

My Main class is located in the following package

```
com.innoConsulting.sitescrapper
```

Comment: The Site's Crapper application could also be getting filtered for bad language by the JVM boostrapping...

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the value of `Main-Class` in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

Your JAR needs a [META-INF/manifest.mf](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) file that spells out where the main class is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a manifest file. See here for a quick explanation: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans either run the project (and it will ask you for the Main-Class) or go into the Project | Properties | Run and select the Main-Class.

Then do another clean and build and it will generate the JAR file with the appropriate manifest file (with the Main-Class: set).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jar file is 'executable'. The Manifest needs to have the Main-Class attribute.